# How to use `file | grep <string>` in a find command?

Tags: linux, file, find, dcmtk

As simple and naïve as it sounds, I'm struggling with the `find` and `file` command. I use `-exec file` because the specific files I need to obtain do not have their extension name in the filename, which eliminates the possiblity of the `-name` option in `find`. See my `find` command and workspace below:

#### My Current Code:

```sh
workspace=/PATH/
### --- Example hierarchy of where all the files needed are located recursively:
##### -----("$workspace"/ID/ID/DICOM/cat)
####### ------- 'cat' is a .dcm file, without ".dcm" in its name

PETS=`find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "DICOM"`
```

#### My current output, which looks like a typical output for `find`:

`./PATH/ID/ID/DICOM/cat: DICOM medical imaging data` (1)

By default, I would've done this to assign it to a variable:

```sh
PETS=($(find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "DICOM"))
```

However, I only get the first instance through this output (when there are many other DICOM files located in relation to the working directory), which almost is a truncated version of my current output above in (1)

`./PATH/ID/ID/DICOM/cat:` (2)

How do I actually obtain the files themselves from (1) or (2), or from a modification of my `find` command, so I can feed it into the [`dcmdump` utility from the dctmk Toolbox](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdump.html)?

Comment: dcmdump supports recursively searching a directory for files. When called with option +fo (--read-file-only) you could also make sure that only DICOM files are actually processed (i.e. parsed) by this tool.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit hairy, but if you can call both `file` and `grep` from within the `-exec` action then you can continue chaining additional actions without needing any intermediate variables.

The way to do it is to create an explicit sub-shell that contains the `file | grep` pipeline: `sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -q DICOM'`. `"$1"` is a placeholder for the file being checked since that's how shell scripts take arguments. (It's not a good idea to embed `{}` inside the script. We'd have issues with special characters like spaces and quotes.)

So how do we set `$1`? The answer by appending arguments to the shell command: `sh -c '<script>' arg0 arg1 arg2...` sets the positional arguments `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc., to the strings `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and so on. Let's do that. We can set `$0` to `sh`, the name of the shell; and `$1` to `{}`, the file name from `find`.

This whole `-exec` action can be treated as a test that passes or fails, no different from a simpler test like `-type f`. We can chain other conditional actions such as a call to `dcmdump`.

All together we get:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -q DICOM' sh {} \; -exec dcmdump {} +
```